# Laravel acces variable from inside $collection->each() loop

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

I want build a new collection from an existing collection using an `each()` loop:

```
$spot = Spot::where('slug', $slug)->first()->load('features.group');

$test = collect();

$spot->features->each(function ($item, $key) {
    $current = collect([
        $item->group->name => $item->name,
    ]);
    $test->mergeRecursive($current);
});
    
dd($test);
```

I am getting the error **Undefined variable $test** from the code inside the loop. How can I access the `$test` collection from inside the loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass data inside the closure by `use()`. Try this:

```
$spot = Spot::where('slug', $slug)->first()->load('features.group');

$test = collect();

$spot->features->each(function ($item, $key) use(&$test) {
    $current = collect([
        $item->group->name => $item->name,
    ]);
    $test->mergeRecursive($current);
});
    
dd($test);
```